# Do you "warrant" or "warranty" your work (or a product/service)?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage

If I offer a warranty for a product or service, can it be said that I *warrant* that product or service? If not, what's the correct verb to use when trying to indicate you offer a warranty on something?

Example:

- "*Yes I warrant all of my work.*"; **or**
- "*Yes I warranty all of my work.*"; **or**
- something else?

Comment: Nope, generally, we guarantee the quality of our work. A warranty requires a widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Warrant* is a verb that can mean, among other things, to make a declaration of truth. It's a fairly archaic term at this point, though, at least in everyday usage, and is likely to be misunderstood as a noun referring to a court document allowing the police to do something.

*Warranty* is a noun that means a written document declaring (warranting) the quality of your product and what you'll do to remedy the situation if it fails to be of the guaranteed quality.

"I warrant all my work" isn't really how you want to say that. You should probably say "I provide a warranty with all my work" instead.

Technically, you could say "I warrant all my work is of the highest quality" or some such thing, but that would sound very old fashioned and probably confuse the listener/reader more than is clarifies things.

You could also say something like "I guarantee all my work", which fits the form you want and would be fully understood today. It's also technically correct, as a warranty is a specific form of guarantee.

Comment: I like confusing people, _warranting_ my work it is!

Comment: I believe "warrant" is a perfectly good verb to describe the act of providing a warranty. Here are some links to legal agreements that say exactly that: [1](http://pdf.lowes.com/productdocuments/3bafec4b-9de1-4b5f-abc9-19eb961b5868/14215549.pdf) [2](https://hytorcwest.ca/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/LionGunWarranty.pdf) [3](https://www.jeld-wen.ca/images/pdf/warranties/canada/JW_United_Warranty_Sheet_Dec_2021.pdf) [4](https://www.owletcare.ca/satisfaction-guarantee-and-limited-warranty)

Comment: One should bear in mind that, depending on the legal system one operates in, one's choice of words in this context may have legal consequences. @hotmeatballsoup, it is unwise to deliberately confuse people in such a context, just because one likes confusing people.